# Why does my function stops reading from a file after ran through once?

Tags: python

My program is set up to read from a .csv file, basically a .txt file. It asks the user for a str to search for, and then searches through this file and prints out the entire line that its on. The user should be able to run the search method multiple times in a row, but it doesnt work after the first time. If it helps, a print statement when put in the search method does show that it indeed runs the second time, just nothing happens. Any ideas why this happens? Thanks.

```
def main():
    print("\nHello, welcome to Sales Data Menu.")
    select=0
    inFile = open("sales_data.csv", "r")
    
    while select != 4:
        select = int(input("\n1.)Search for an inovice item based on last name or id number.\n2.)Find and display the total number of items on the invoice.\n3.)Find and display the total cost of the invoice.\n4.)Exit the menu.\nEnter a number to select an option to do:  "))
        if select==1:
            search(inFile)
        else:
            print("You did not enter a valid integer. Please re-enter")
        
    inFile.close()
    
    
def search(inFile):
    item = input("Enter a last name or an id number to search by.")
    for lines in inFile:
        if item in lines:
            print(lines)
```

Comment: Can you try opening the file within the `search` function? E.g. pass the filename as argument, but open  and close it inside the function. This will create a new buffered text stream each time through which you then iterate in the function. Also try using context handlers (`with`) to open your files and then close them automatically

Comment: @Gamer--did the previous answer and comments by others help solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_close.htm

Python file method close() closes the opened file. A closed file cannot be read or written any more. Any operation, which requires that the file be opened will raise a ValueError after the file has been closed. Calling close() more than once is allowed.

the problem is probably on that line:

```
inFile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, but moving/deleting that line doesnt change anything

Answer (score 1):

When you use the file object itself in a loop, behind the scenes python calls `inFile.next()` repeatedly until it reaches EOF. Looping it again doesn't reset the counter.

If you want to loop the content multiple times, you can read the whole content into memory by making it a python list of lines `lines = inFile.readlines()`, then you can loop over `lines` as many times as you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are few different ways to achieve what you need here.
The current code will read all lines in the file, hence the file pointer (like a *reading head* scanning over the file) will be at the end after the first search.

Now, the thing is that **file pointers do not reset automatically**, that is, you must manually put it back at the beginning of the file.

The simplest way to fix your current code is to insert a `file.seek(0)` operation in the `search()` function, like this:

```
def main():
    print("\nHello, welcome to Sales Data Menu.")
    select=0
    inFile = open("sales_data.csv", "r")
    
    while select != 4:
        select = int(input("\n1.)Search for an inovice item based on last name or id number.\n2.)Find and display the total number of items on the invoice.\n3.)Find and display the total cost of the invoice.\n4.)Exit the menu.\nEnter a number to select an option to do:  "))
        if select==1:
            search(inFile)
        else:
            print("You did not enter a valid integer. Please re-enter")
        
    inFile.close()
    
    
def search(inFile):
    item = input("Enter a last name or an id number to search by.")
    for lines in inFile:
        if item in lines:
            print(lines)
    inFile.seek(0)  # this resets the file pointer, so the next operation will start from the beginning of the file
```